# Minimizing the multivariable function $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{xy} + x^2y$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I need to locate the optimal point(s) of the function $$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{xy} + x^2y$$ subject to the conditions $x \gt 0, y \gt 0$.

I have tried the following approach
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{-1}{x^2y} + 2xy = 0 \rightarrow 1$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{-1}{xy^2} + x^2 = 0 \rightarrow 2$$
Now, $x \ne 0, y \ne 0,$ hence, we solve the two equations to get the optimal point, $(x^*, y^*)$. But the above system of equations has no solution.

Physically, when $x \rightarrow 0$ or $y \rightarrow 0$, the function blows up. Also, when either $x \rightarrow \infty$ or $y \rightarrow \infty$, the function also blows up. Since it takes finite values in between and is continuous and differentiable, it should have some minimum value(s), and hence an optimal point.

Where am I going wrong ?

**SOLVED**

Thanks to Arthur, I have realised the error in the above statements. I have assumed that whenever x or y becomes large, the function will blow up. But if I were to go along the path $y = \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^3}}$, and take $x$ smaller and smaller, $f = 2\sqrt x$ will go to 0. Hence, the infimum is $0$

Comment: The Extreme Value Theorem holds for compact sets, while $\mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R}^+$ is not bounded, hence do not satisfies the theorem's requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$C=\{(x,y)|x>0,y>0\}$ is not compact.

Thus, we can get the situation for which a minimal value does not exist.

It's exactly which happens in our case.

By AM-GM
$$\frac{1}{xy}+x^2y\geq2\sqrt{\frac{1}{xy}\cdot x^2y}=2\sqrt{x}.$$
The equality occurs for $\frac{1}{xy}=x^2y$ or $x^3y^2=1$.

Since, for $x\rightarrow0^+$ we get $\sqrt{x}\rightarrow0^+$, we obtain that 
$$\inf\left(\frac{1}{xy}+x^2y\right)=0$$

Comment: This just says that $f(x,y) \gt 0$, it says nothing about it's minimum value

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Actually, it does. It shows that along the curve $y = \sqrt{1/x^3}$, as you move to smaller and smaller $x$, and thus larger and larger $y$, the function value continues to decrease toward $0$. It doesn't completely rule out the existence of _local_ minima, but it shows that you made an error in judgement when you assumed that the function value increases as we move far away from the origin, which was your reason for assuming a minimum exists.

Comment: @Dhanvi Sreenivasan I proved that the minimum does not exist and the infimum equal to $0$.